# How does $\int\limits_0^\infty{{x^{v-1}}{e^{-\frac{\beta}{x}-\gamma x}}dx}=2{({\frac{\beta}{\gamma}})^{\frac{v}{2}}}{K_v}({2\sqrt{\beta\gamma}})$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I have been reading Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's [Table of Integrals, Series, and Products
7th Edition](https://www.elsevier.com/books/table-of-integrals-series-and-products/jeffrey/978-0-08-047111-2) and see the 9th integral in chapter 3 section 3.471.

$$\int\limits_0^\infty{{x^{v-1}}{e^{-\frac{\beta}{x}-\gamma x}}dx}=2{({\frac{\beta}{\gamma}})^{\frac{v}{2}}}{K_v}({2\sqrt{\beta\gamma}})$$

Where $\operatorname{Real} \left( \beta  \right) > 0,\operatorname{Real} \left( \gamma  \right) > 0$

The book does not provide any detail explanations on why the **Bessel function** just pop up in the answer so are there anyway to solve this integral explicitly step by step ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: This identity is referenced in [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the definition of $K$ (second equation after the the graphs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1
\begin{eqnarray*}
K_{\alpha}(x)= \int_0^{\infty} e^{x \cosh t } \cosh( \alpha t) dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now try the substitution
\begin{eqnarray*}
x= \sqrt{ \frac{\beta}{\gamma} } e^t \\ 
\frac{dx}{x} =  dt
\end{eqnarray*}
and your integral becomes
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \left( \sqrt{ \frac{\beta}{\gamma} } e^t\right)^{\nu} e^{- \sqrt{ \beta \gamma} (e^t+e^{-t})} dt
\end{eqnarray*}
Now split the interval integral at zero and sub $e^t+e^{-t}=2 \cosh(t)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
=  \left( \sqrt{ \frac{\beta}{\gamma} } \right)^{\nu} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( e^{ \nu t} + e^{-\nu t} \right) e^{- 2\sqrt{ \beta \gamma}  \cosh (t) } dt
\end{eqnarray*}
and the result follows.

Comment: I am sorry but where does $\sqrt {\beta \gamma } \cosh \left( t \right)$ at the equal sign in the second last integral from negative infinity to positive infinity come from ?. I am sorry but in my major this function is not popularly known.